# Why is there no warning or error when initializing a const pointer to null?

Tags: c++, pointers, null, nullptr

This might be a very basic question, but I tried to find the answer in SO and couldn't find the exact answer to it.

What's the point of initializing a `const` pointer with `nullptr`?

```
int *const pi = nullptr;
```

Why does the compiler not emit a warning or error, seeing how pointer `pi` can't be used effectively anywhere in the program?

I have tried compiling this with `g++ -w`.

Also, Can you give some use case where a `const` pointer will get initialized to `nullptr` for a valid purpose in real code?

Comment: Because a nullptr is not invalid. I guess for a numerical value like "pi" it doesn't really make sense, but that's your choice as a developer. It's still valid code. As an example, I could imagine having a (const) pointer as null (forever) on purpose because some functionality is disabled depending on the instantiation of a class.

Comment: `nullptr` is a valid value for a pointer, there's no reason it should not be allowed. `if(something == pi)` is still valid.

Comment: "pi can't be used effectively anywhere in the program." why do you think so? I can be used effectively anywhere where you can use a `nulltpr`. It isnt wrong, just not very useful to give a different name to `nullptr`

Comment: Why would one want to forbid this? Likewise you could say why something like `(true and false and true and false)` should be forbidden because it evaluates to `false` anyway. The standards are not there to check your semantics.

Comment: @Aziuth smart compiler should through warning for this, isn't it?  something like a **warning: expression always evaluates to false**.

Comment: @Cedric: "Not invalid" means it's not an error, it doesn't mean there shouldn't be a warning.

Comment: nothing in normative documents require diagnostics in this situation, so there is no "should". If anything, you declared a legal immutable null object (pattern)

Comment: @einpoklum Indeed, a warning would be possible. I don't know the real reason why no warning is given, but as it is a "conceivably sensible" way to use the language, such a warning would be highly annoying in practice imho. Unlike e.g. `if (unsigned_type_value < 0)`, in which case one would clearly expect a user mistake.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: Note that the question has been edited not to focus on the language standard but on compiler behavior. Due disclosure: I made that edit, believing that it better reflects what OP wants to kow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree that initializing a `const` pointer to `nullptr` isn't *generally* especially useful, one situation where it *may* me appropriate is where you would *conditionally* define the `const pi` pointer to either `nullptr` or some other (valid) address, depending on a compile-time setting, like in the following example. (The `const` qualifier prevents other code from inadvertently changing the value and, thusly, breaking the aforementioned compile-time condition.)

```cpp
#include<iostream>  

#define USENULL 1 // Comment out this line to get a 'valid' pointer!

int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    #ifdef USENULL
    int* const pi = nullptr;
    #else
    int* const pi = &a;
    #endif
    int* pa = pi;
    if (pa) std::cout << *pa;
    else std::cout << "null pointer";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Such a situation could arise when you need to differentiate between debug and release builds, for example.

Comment: I think the first example is inappropriate. Masking `nullptr` in order to save a few keystrokes is bad coding practice IMHO. Consider only keeping the second one, which is more valid.

Comment: @einpoklum Agreed - we don't want to encourage bad coding practices on SO! Edited to remove that.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse `const`, which means: "The values cannot change after initialization" with "this value is always, under all circumstances a `nullptr`". What I mean is this:

```
 struct foo {
     int *const pi = nullptr;
     foo( int* p) : pi(p) {}
 };
```

Different instances of `foo` can have different values for `pi`.

Another way to have the initialization conditional is:

```
 int *const pi = (some_condition) ? nullptr : some_pointer;
```

Even with a plain

```
 int *const pi = nullptr;
```

there is nothing wrong. It is basically giving a different name to `nullptr`, so you can use `pi` anywhere where you can use a `nullptr`. For example as sentinel in a container:

```
 int * const empty = nullptr;
 for ( int* element : container) {
     if (element != empty) do_something(element);
 }
```

This might be considered obfuscation, and directly using `nullptr` would be more readable. Though consider the sentinel value changes later on, then using `empty` makes is simple to replace all occurences of it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to generalize @AdrianMole's (second) example:

Sometimes, a piece of code is a **degenerate case** or an **outlier case** of a more general instruction or pattern. Thus:

- In @AdrianMole's example, there is an out-of-source parameter which controls whether `pi` should have a meaningful value or not. You don't want to twist your source up too much in order to accommodate this scenario, so you keep the same code but use `nullptr`, likely with a later (run-time) check for whether you have a `nullptr` or not.
- You might have a template class where the general definition is something like:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  class A  {
  int *const pi = whatever<T>();
  }
  ```

  with a specialization

  ```
  template <>
  class A<foo_t>  {
  int *const pi = nullptr;
  }
  ```

  because you want to avoid calling `whatever<foo>()`.

It is likely that such code can be improved to avoid the explicit `nullptr` assignment. But it would be a bit excessive to push developers into doing this through a warning.

(An error is out of the question since it's perfectly valid code in terms of the language standard.)